# How to make a igraph object with a list of objects?

Tags: python, list, igraph

I have a list of "treenode" objects.

Each "treenode" has 3 attributes, all strings.

I tried following the tutorial [here](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html#generating-graphs)

However, I cannot add the nodes.

My current code:

```
testlist = []
for elem in mytree1.iter():
    testlist.append(treenode(elem.tag,elem.attrib,elem.text))

G = Graph()
for x in testlist:
    G.add_vertices(x)
```

The error I get:

```
an integer is required (got type treenode)
```

How should I go about using a list to add nodes to the igraph?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`add_vertex`](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#add_vertex) method to add a single node and get back the newly added node as a `Vertex` object, which can then be used to set its properties.

```py
G = graph()
for x in testlist:
    v = G.add_vertex()
    v["tag"] = x.tag
    v["attrib"] = x.attrib
    v["text"] = x.text
```

[Here](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html#setting-and-retrieving-attributes) is an explanation of why *igraph* works this way.